# When Schroedinger propagator commutes other operators?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis, schrodinger-operators

Let $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)$ (Schwartz Space).

We know  that $\widehat{\nabla f}(\xi)= 2 \pi i \xi \hat{f} (\xi). $ We define $$\widehat{|\nabla| f^{s}} (\xi) = (2 \pi |\xi|)^s \hat{f} (\xi), (s\in \mathbb R).$$

We may now define that $$(- \Delta) ^{s/2}f= |\nabla | f^s, (s\in \mathbb R).$$

We define Little wood-Paley projection associated to $-\Delta$
as follows: Let
$\phi:[0, \infty) \to \infty$
 be a smooth functin such that 
$\phi(\lambda) =1$ for $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$ and $ \phi(\lambda)=0$ for $ \lambda \geq 2.$

For each dyadic number $N \in 2^{\mathbb Z},$ we define $\phi_N(\lambda) = \phi(\lambda/N)$ and $\psi_N(\lambda) = \phi_N(\lambda)- \phi_{N/2}(\lambda).$ We define the Little wood-Paley projection as follos:

$$\widehat{P_Nf} = \psi_N \hat{f}.$$

(And so $P_Nf=  (\psi_N)^{\vee} \ast f$)

Now we define  $\mathcal{L}_a$ as the  Friedrich extension of the operator $-\Delta + \frac{a}{|x|^2}$ (initially defined on $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d\setminus \{0\})$)  See [Section 1.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02716.pdf) for details

Authors (in the same paper page 16) define the Little wood-Paley projections associated to $\mathcal{L}_a$ as follows:
 $$P_N^a:= \psi_N(\sqrt{\mathcal{L}_a}),$$

and associated to heat kernel
$$\tilde{P}_n^a= e^{-\mathcal{L}_a/N^2}-e^{-4\mathcal{L}_a/ N^2}$$

[We may use  [Spectral Theorem (and page 8)](http://homepage.sns.it/fricci/papers/multipliers.pdf)  to define $m(\mathcal{L}_a)]$

> My  Basic Questions: (1)  Can we say $P_n^a=m(\mathcal{L}_a) \tilde{P}_N^a$ ? (In other words, how these Lilltewood-Paley projections are related?)
>   (2) Is $P_n^ae^{-it\mathcal{L}_a} f=e^{-it\mathcal{L}_a} P_N^a f$ ? Is $\nabla e^{-it\mathcal{L}_a} f = e^{-it\mathcal{L}_a}\nabla f$? (In other words, when Schroedinger propagator commutes  with Littlewood Paley projections)

Note. See also Theorem 1.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02716.pdf)